# Filter and sort in gridview with junction table in yii2

Tags: php, sql, gridview, yii2

I have 3 tables:

```
TABLE projects (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name text NOT NULL,
);
TABLE project_participants (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    proj_id integer REFERENCES projects (id) NOT NULL,
);
TABLE valuations (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    proj_partic_id integer REFERENCES project_participants (id) NOT NULL,
    tehn_knowledge numeric NOT NULL,
    comunication_skills numeric NOT NULL,
);
```

and functions in Projects model:

```
    public function  getValuations() {
    return $this->hasMany(Valuations::className(), ['proj_partic_id' => 'id'])
        ->viaTable('project_participants', ['proj_id' => 'id']);
}

public function getValuationsSum() {
    $sum = 0;
    foreach ($this->valuations as $val){

        $sum += $val->tehn_knowledge;
        $sum += $val->comunication_skills;
    }
    return $sum;
}
```

So in gridview I can show summary data like:

```
        'columns' => [
                    'valuationsSum',
```

But now I want to search and filter values, but can't write working query in projectsSearch model. :( Tried:

```
        $query = Projects::find();

    $subQuery = Valuations::find(Valuations::className(), ['proj_partic_id' => 'id'])
        ->viaTable('project_participants', ['proj_id' => 'id'])
        ->select('proj_partic_id, SUM(tehn_knowledge + comunication_skills) as rating')
        ->groupBy('project_participants.id');

    $query->leftJoin([
        'valuation'=>$subQuery
    ]);
```

and after `$this->load($params);`

added

```
$query->andFilterWhere([
           'valuation.rating' => $this->valuationsSum,
```

But seems this $subQuery is absolutely wrong. Tried to write it similar to example [here](http://webtips.krajee.com/filter-sort-summary-data-gridview-yii-2-0/), but I have this junction table.

Comment: have you found the solution? I am having the same problem.

Comment: @KirillRyzhkov - I created a database view for all data needed in gridview.

Comment: ok, thank you for the answer